# How to combine two mongodb query document in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have two queries like this, 
and I need to combine these queries into one query.

```
var query = new QueryDocument("Type", Type);
var query1 = new QueryDocument("Name", search.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
var query = Query.And(query1, query2, ...);
```